# Odoo 15 - Redirect users to a specific form/action when they login

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I'd like to redirect my users to the hr_attendance module when they login, I tried to change the home action from users preference, but when I change that, my modules menu doesn't work correctly and show me all time the hr_attendance action when I access other modules.

Anyone could help me? Thanks!! :)

I tried to change the home action from users preference, but when I change that, my modules menu doesn't work correctly and show me all time the hr_attendance action when I access other modules

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could add  this hidden `<input>` field inside your xml code of your `<form>` which will redirect to the /shop webpage after submitting the form:

```html
<form ...>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/shop" />
</form>
```